# Normalizing the data using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, math, normalization

## I have the below data

df1

```
    Hema    shiva   Ishan
0   22  30  33
1   34  32  21
2   20  12  14
3   26  14  18
4   12  28  17
5   30  11  22
6   18  15  18
7   19  18  19
8   22  20  32
```

I wanted to take ratio of first column value with rest of the columns , eg first column should divide by 22 , 2nd column 30 and 3rd columns by 33 .

- **The answer is below .**

[image]

Please help me if I missing something

Answer (score 3):

Just divide the first row by the DF:

```
df.iloc[0] / df
```